# setInterval not working after first 5 iterations

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

Im trying to make the cron function run every `randomInterval` number of seconds.

I changed `setInterval(cron(), randomInterval);` to `setInterval(cron, randomInterval);` which removed the maximum call stack error. But this will still not act as a good reliable cron. After the first 5 iterations it will execute the cron function with out setting  an interval.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

```
function cron() {
    randomInterval = randomIntFromInterval(1000, 9000);

    cronInterval = setInterval(cron, randomInterval);
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

cron();
```

The code below has the tests logging out the intervals and also when the cron fires.

```
function cron() {
    var d = new Date();

    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;

    console.log(h + ":" + m + "took screenshot ");

    randomInterval = randomIntFromInterval(1000, 9000);

    cronInterval = setInterval(cron, randomInterval);
    console.log(randomInterval/1000);
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

cron()
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after, but your are setting an interval which will continue firing in the callback over and over until cancelled and each time it runs, it sets up a new interval. The result is lots of intervals going at the same time. Maybe you want to use `setTimeout()` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using setInterval which will keep on executing the same cron function after every (arbitrary number) N milliseconds. If you want to implement a cron like functionality use setTimeout instead of setInterval. Because setInterval will quickly fill your event queue with a lot of callback functions and you will eventually get stack overflow or memory overflow type of error.

setInterval never stops calling the callback until you make it stop. What your code is doing is it is filling up the event queue with a lot of callbacks which is creating the problem.

```
function cron() {
    var d = new Date();

    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;

    console.log(h + ":" + m + "took screenshot ");

    randomInterval = randomIntFromInterval(1000, 9000);

    cronInterval = setTimeout(cron, randomInterval); // Here change it to setTimeout
    console.log(randomInterval/1000);
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

cron()
```